# Scrollable large NSDocument on Macbook Pro 13" XGA display

Tags: macos, cocoa, scroll, nswindow, nsscrollview

I'm having all kinds of trouble understanding how `NSWindows` can have larger documents than the window bounds in them.

Unfortunately, layout and contents prevents me from simply shrinking the document (and I wouldn't want to make the layout cramped for those with larger screens).

A school needs to run this app on their new 13", non-retina MacBook Pros. Scrolling is acceptable to them, but I'm unsure as to the approach, and I'd like your advice on the best way to handle this to avoid forced scrolling on larger screens.

I've tried setting the `NSWindow` min and max size and embedding the document in a Scroll View. But even though you can see part of the document view sticking out, no scroll bars appear  (I have set them to **Always** in sys prefs).

If this is the way to go I would appreciate a link to a tutorial on this exact subject, because I'm a bit lost with all the measurements and options.

If not I'd like a pointer where to start and what to read. I'm experienced with Cocoa Touch but a relative newcomer to Mac development.

Comment: What kind of document (or NSDocument) are you trying to display? If it's something like a PDF or HTML, there are other things you can do to zoom in and out or present the document appropriately.

Comment: It's a subclassed NSView with many dynamic labels and text fields. I could make the font size even smaller or cramp the elements together, but this would make it hard to read, even on non-retina screens.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information it sounds like you have embedded a `NSScrollView` but didn't set up the springs and struts properly to allow the scroll view to resize when its parent view (assuming it's the window) resizes.

You might want to check out [Specifying a View’s Behavior as Its Container Resizes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#recipes/xcode_help-interface_builder/articles/Autosizing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009971-CH13-SW1) in the **Interface Builder Help** documentation.

Comment: I've embedded something *in* a scrollview. Do you mean I should check the springs and struts for the element outside the scrollview? (It's an NSView which is in an NSWindow.) I have no struts or springs like for UIView subclasses anywhere. Do you mean the Constraints?

Comment: Checking the right constraint's box "Standard" makes the vertical scrollbar appear, and if I manually drag it, the scrolling works :) **BUT** there is no response to dragging or mouse-scrolling. Am I looking at some focus issue next? (Why isn't this in the default behavior when embedding??)